# Run Android application in multiple devices at the same time (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Like in Android Studio i would like to know if there is any chance to have Xamarin Studio to run the application in multiples devices / emulators at the same time.

I've posted this issue as a feature request on Xamarin bugzilla.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As announced [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39356), this feature it's gonna be released in the next Stable Xamarin Studio version. This was developed in [Cycle 8 Feature Release](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65487/alpha-release-cycle-8-feature-release-preview/p1).

Comment: any word on this for visual studio 2015?

Comment: Xamarin Studio now support the deploy to multiples devices, but I guess that feature is only available in XS.